# kinect obstacle avoidance

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, 3d-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done the segmentation in the point cloud and cluster in the point cloud. Now, I have to implement the obstacle avoidance. I wonder how can I find a good algorithm for path planning? Is there any PCL API can help me to do path opening (gap between 2 clusters).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207848/kinect-obstacle-avoidance/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you trying to plan a manipulator path between point cloud clusters, or are you trying to navigate a mobile robot between two obstacles?

If you're trying to plan a manipulator, use MoveIt and add collision objects to your scene that correspond to the location of the clusters. Your manipulator will automatically plan around them.

If you're trying to move a mobile robot, take a look into SLAM for automatic collision avoidance and mapping.

You should be able to use PCL to find the bounding boxes of two point clouds and then calculate the minimum distance between them. This would be your gap distance.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-05-02**:
already done the bounding box. but it doesnt give me good result. especially, when i have a chair with a gap underneath, the box includes everything. its not a very optimal approach

**Comment by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on 2015-05-03**:
If your bounding box includes everything, then you're not looking for the distance between two clusters as you said above. I'm trying to answer the original question - a gap between two clusters.

As I said above, look into SLAM-based nav: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials